# Pandas Dataframe to nested XML

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have a pandas Dataframe like this:

```
  TECHNOLOGY LOT_KEY DEVICE  wet1   wet2
0      tech1   lot11  dev11  1.00  1.100
1      tech1   lot12  dev12  1.11  1.111
2      tech2   lot21  dev21  2.00  2.200
3      tech2   lot22  dev21  2.22  2.222
```

That I want to convert into a nested XML like this:

```
<ALL_DATA>

<TECHNOLOGY>tech1
    <DEVICE>dev11
        <LOT_KEY>lot11
            <WET>SOME DATA HERE</WET>
        </LOT_KEY>
    </DEVICE>
    <DEVICE>dev12
        <LOT_KEY>lot12
            <WET>SOME DATA HERE</WET>
        </LOT_KEY>
    </DEVICE>
</TECHNOLOGY>

<TECHNOLOGY>tech2
    <DEVICE>dev21
        <LOT_KEY>lot21
            <WET>SOME DATA HERE</WET>
        </LOT_KEY>
        <LOT_KEY>lot22
            <WET>SOME DATA HERE</WET>
        </LOT_KEY>
    </DEVICE>

</TECHNOLOGY>

</ALL_DATA>
```

I have looked at other examples but they seem to be flat XMLs without nesting. Is there a built in Dataframe to XML routine in pandas? What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?